# Как перехватить sms в android?

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

Мне нужно перехватить сообщения от +15555215554 и создать уведомления с новым названием и тем же текстом но почему ето не происходит? Буду благодарен!Использую виртуал девайс на 7 андроиде!

```
class SMSMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null &&
                ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
            Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);
            }
            String sms_from = messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            if (sms_from.equalsIgnoreCase("+15555215554")) {
                StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    bodyText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
                }
                String body = bodyText.toString();
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, SmsService.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
                context.startService(mIntent);

                abortBroadcast();
            }
        }
    }
}

class SmsService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    private void showNotification(String text) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Rugball catch")
                .setContentText(text)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(R.drawable.ic_launcher, builder.build());
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String sms_body = intent.getExtras().getString("sms_body");
        showNotification(sms_body);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appsms" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver
            android:name=".SMSMonitor"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Мне надо перехватить для начала sms которое я отправляю с емулятора с номера +15555215554 самому себе!

Comment: а в пермишены добавил разрешение? Плюс нужно у пользователя запросить разрешение на чтение смс.

Comment: Вот скинул пермишены! А что за разрешения на чтение смс? я сделал только запрос разрешения при отправке смс. Смс отправляет и приходит уведомления от стандартного месенджера, а мне нужно создать свое уведомления.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814922/why-does-android-ignore-read-sms-permission

Comment: @tosh17 спасибо, я уже разобрался, там была проблема з созданием нового уведомления